# Join pandas dataframes with column having pipe delimited values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe df2 with one of the column with comma separated values. I would like to join df2 with another dataframe df1 using label first and if match not found then use synonym column. The synonym column can also have more than 2 values.

```
df1
label
Werner syndrome
Ageing

df2
id   label                 synonym
1    Werner's syndrome     Werner syndrome|Werner disease
2    Ageing
```

Expected output is:

```
df
label              id     label                 synonym
Werner syndrome    1      Werner's syndrome     Werner syndrome|Werner disease
Ageing             2      Ageing
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Id `id` unique in `df2`?

Comment: Yes, Id values are unique

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by first expanding the synonym column in df2 into multiple rows, then performing a join operation on df1 and df2 using both label and synonym columns.

Here's how you can do it:

```
import pandas as pd

# Assuming df1 and df2 are your dataframes

# Split the synonym column into multiple rows
df2 = df2.assign(synonym=df2['synonym'].str.split('|')).explode('synonym')

# Perform the join operation
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='left', left_on='label', right_on='synonym')

# If label from df1 is not found in synonym, try to join on label from df2
df.loc[df['id'].isna(), 'id':'synonym'] = df1.merge(df2, how='left', on='label').loc[df['id'].isna(), 'id':'synonym']

# Reset the index
df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
```

In this code, df2.assign(synonym=df2['synonym'].str.split('|')).explode('synonym') splits the synonym column into multiple rows. Then, pd.merge(df1, df2, how='left', left_on='label', right_on='synonym') performs a left join on df1 and df2 using the label column from df1 and the synonym column from df2. If a label from df1 is not found in synonym, it tries to join on label from df2. Finally, df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True) resets the index of the resulting dataframe.

Comment: As a reminder, [AI-generated answers are banned from this platform](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1)